# Query Data From Database Using Date Range in PHP/MySQL

Tags: php, mysql, database

I am new here is the script index.php of query data from database using date range in PHP/MySQL.

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="tcal.css" />
<script type="text/javascript" src="tcal.js"></script>
<form action="index.php" method="get">
From : <input type="text" name="d1" class="tcal" value="" /> To: <input type="text" name="d2" class="tcal" value="" /> <input type="submit" value="Search">
</form>
<table id="resultTable" data-responsive="table" style="text-align: left; width: 400px;" border="1" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="4">
<thead>
<tr>
<th> Birtday </th>
<th> Name </th>
<th> Gender </th>
</tr>
</thead>
<tbody>
<?php
include('connect.php');
if (isset($_GET["d1"])) { $d1 = $_GET["d1"]; } else { $d1=0; };
if (isset($_GET["d2"])) { $d2 = $_GET["d2"]; } else { $d2=0; };
$result = $db->prepare("SELECT * FROM birthday WHERE date BETWEEN :a AND :b");
$result->bindParam(':a', $d1);
$result->bindParam(':b', $d2);
$result->execute();
for($i=0; $row = $result->fetch(); $i++){
?>
<tr class="record">
<td><?php echo $row['date']; ?></td>
<td><?php echo $row['name']; ?></td>
<td><?php echo $row['gender']; ?></td>
</tr>
<?php
}
?>
</tbody>
</table>
```

Now in this script we have 2 calenders for using the date range... Some one here who edit this script make into only 1 calender  for selecting date.

Comment: Choosing a date range with just 1 input? Hmm...

Comment: yes i want to just 1 input

Answer (score 0, accepted):

PHP stores dates in the format "YYYY-MM-DD". I presume that the input for calendar would return date in the above format.
Rest of the code looks pretty good to me but you need to change this

```
{ $d1=0; };
```

To

```
{ $d1="0000-00-00"; };
```

Answer (score 0):

If you remove references to d2 and change the query to this, it should work:

```
$result = $db->prepare("SELECT * FROM birthday WHERE date = :a ");
```